# Rename files in directory and table based on a combination of columns

Tags: php, mysql, file-rename

I have a table named `locations` in MySQL and a directory folder with images. Now i need a way in order to rename images (both in directory and table) by combine different columns and also words and a serial number for each.

In table `locations` the fields are `image_filename`, `title`, `location`, and `area`.

Is it possible to rename `image_filename` by concatenate field `title`, a serial number, the word `Sailing`, field `location`, field `area` and the word `Greece`?

Let's say I have an image with title `location_158`and I want to rename (both in directory and table) as

Bay Diamanti (`title`) + a serial number + the word 'Sailing' + Myconos (`location`) + Cyclades (`area`) + word 'Greece'

Bay-diamanti-1-Sailing-Myconos-Cyclades-Greece

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it was only sql, you could do it like this: update locations set image_filename=concat(replace(title," ",""),"-", serialnumber,"-", "Sailing","-",location, "-",area, "Greece"). As you need to update the filename, I would do a "select" query with all the locations, loop and I would construct the new name in php, then update both filename and table.

Comment: @netadictos thanks for your response, this actually works but the serial number must be automated. Some thing that i forgot to mention is that records they don't have all image.

Comment: The procedure continues to be the same, I suppose, only change the select query. You only have to find the right php functions to build what I suggest and change the filenames.